# How to fetch Distinct Contacts from Phone in android

Tags: java, android

I want to fetch unique contacts from phone; now it is showing duplicates. It is fetching phone contacts, SIM contacts and also gmail account contacts.

```
public void readContacts() {

    name.clear();
    number.clear();

    content_resolver = getContentResolver();
    cursor = content_resolver.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
            null, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            number.add(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
            name.add(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    simCursor = this.getContentResolver().query(simUri, null, null, null,
            null);
    if (simCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            number.add(simCursor.getString(simCursor
                    .getColumnIndex("number")));
            name.add(simCursor.getString(simCursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
        } while (simCursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
}
```

Comment: anybody there to help me...............for above question

Comment: Do u require unique details from phone or sim

Comment: Both the sim and the phone contacts might be same you can sort it out with the collection frame work to make it unique values

Comment: Can u plz send me any link related to that....

Comment: Should i need to use Set in Collection ?

Comment: All the links refers to the get the contacts but you need to customize it accordingly kindly refer to it http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/06/get-phone-contacts-details-in-android_6.html

Comment: store the contacts with any kind of unique set values